# mostrar un archivo de texto c++

Tags: c++

estoy realizando un ejercicio del juego de ahorcado y el esta bien, compila y hace su funcion

sin embargo el problema es que la opcion de GUARDAR TABLA DE RECORDS tendria que mostrar el archivo txt en la pantalla y no lo hace
ya añadi un ios en ifstream y ofstream pero sigue sin funcionar :(
alguien podria revisarlo porfavor ? no se en que esta fallando, es un codigo super grande y pues ya revise casi todo, detalle por detalle pero mas creo que el error esta en la parte final, porque al guardar el archivo funciona todo bien, sin embargo lo escribe siempre como si fuera la primera vez que el archivo se abre

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
string PQWAR;
string ga[100];
int ga1[100];
int intentos = 5;
int record = 0;
int pistas = 3, aux1 = 0;
bool encontrar = false;
int encontrar2 = 0;
bool usuarioganador = false;
bool jugando = true;
int a1 = 0;

void iniciar();
void escribir_archivo();

int main(){
 int op = 0;
 while(op != 3){
 cout<<"Seleccione una opcion\n 1) JUGAR\n 2) GUARDAR TABLA DE GANADORES \n 3) SALIR"<<endl;
 cin>>op;
  switch(op){
   case 1:iniciar();break;
   case 2:escribir_archivo();break;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}

void iniciar(){
 intentos = 5;
 record = 0;
 pistas = 3, aux1 = 0;
 usuarioganador = false;
 PQWAR = "";
 cout<<"Introduzca alguna palabra para jugar: \n";
 cin>>PQWAR;
 system("cls");
 char current[100];
 for(int i = 0; i < strlen(PQWAR.c_str()); i++ ){
  if(pistas > 0){
   srand (time(NULL));
   aux1 = rand() % 3 + 1;
   if(aux1 == 1){
    current[i] = PQWAR[i];
    pistas--;
   }else{
    current[i] = '_';
   }
  }else{
   current[i] = '_';
  }
 }
 std::string answer = "";
 while(intentos > 0){
  answer = "";
  encontrar = false; encontrar2 = 0;
  cout<<current<<"\nintroduzca una palabra o letra\n";
  cin>>answer;
  if(strlen(answer.c_str()) < 2){
   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(PQWAR.c_str()); i++){
    if(answer[0] == PQWAR[i]){
     current[i] = answer[0];
     record += 5;
     encontrar = true;
    }
   }
   if(encontrar == false){
    intentos--;
    cout<<"INCORRECTO intentos restantes: "<<intentos<<endl;
   }else{
    cout<<"CORRECTO puntuacion: "<<record<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(PQWAR.c_str()); i++){
     if(current[i] == '_'){
      encontrar2 = 1;
     }
    }
    if(encontrar2 != 1){
     usuarioganador = true;
     break;
    }
   }
  }else{
   encontrar2 = strcmp(answer.c_str(), PQWAR.c_str());
   if(encontrar2 == 1){
    intentos--;
    cout<<"INCORRECTO intentos restantes: "<<intentos<<endl;
   }else{
    record = strlen(PQWAR.c_str()) * 5;
    cout<<"CORRECTO puntuacion: "<<record<<endl;
    usuarioganador = true;
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 if(usuarioganador){
  string temporalW;
  cout<<"FELICIDADES \n";
  cin>>temporalW;
  ga1[a1] = record;
  ga[a1] = temporalW + "_____________________ [ ";
  a1++;
 }
  system("cls");
}

void escribir_archivo(){
 ofstream archivo;
 archivo.open("jk.txt",ios_base::app);
 archivo<<" Tabla de Ganadores";
 archivo<<"\n";
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  if(ga[i] != ""){
   archivo<<"-----------------------------------------------------------------\n";
   archivo<<ga[i]<<ga1[i]<<" ]\n"<<endl;
  }
 }
 archivo.close();
 ifstream archivo2;  //nombre que utilizare para acceder
    archivo.open("jk.txt",ios::in); //abrimos archivo ya existente
    if(!archivo){
        cout<<"Error al abrir el archivo"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int PQWAR,ga,intentos,record,pistas,encontrar,encontrar2,usuarioganador,jugando,a1;              //Declaramos variable que contiene la informacion
while(archivo2>>PQWAR>>ga>>intentos>>record>>pistas>>encontrar>>encontrar2>>usuarioganador>>jugando>>a1){  //mostramos informacion
    cout<<' '<<PQWAR<<ga<<intentos<<record<<pistas<<encontrar<<encontrar2<<usuarioganador<<jugando<<a1;
}
archivo.close();          //cerramos archivo
cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas escribiendo el archivo en un formato, y leyéndolo en otro distinto. Cuando lo escribes, se ve así:

```
 Tabla de ganadores
-----------------------------------------------------------------
XXX_____________________ [ YYY ]
```

pero cuando lo lées, esperas leer una lista de números enteros en cada línea. La condición en el `while` falla al primer intento (en la linea `" Tabla de ganadores"`), y por eso no muestra nada.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en esta parte de tu código

```cpp
     ifstream archivo2;  //nombre que utilizare para acceder
        archivo.open("jk.txt",ios::in); //abrimos archivo ya existente
```

Cuando haces el archivo.open, no deberías hacerlo con ese archivo sino con archivo2.open